# How to force users to use email address in lowercase in GIT

Tags: git, shell, github, filter, email-validation

I'm looking for possibilities to confirm whether the email address of the committer is lower case to avoid issues like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/12373/how-do-i-edit-gits-history-to-correct-an-incorrect-email-address-name).

I'm thinking to implement a client side pre-commit hook script which would either convert the upper case into lower case characters in the username and email or just warns the user to change in git config.

I don't want to write something like this every time I encounter with errors during import. This is not recommended, as it results in modification in the ref values and might break some contents.

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter 'export
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="yourname@example.com";GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Yourname"'
```

Please suggest me if there is any other better ways to achieve the same.

Comment: Why is email casing causing you "import errors"? (Whatever that even means since you don't explain.)

Comment: @etan, Because of the limitation in Gerrit where git repos are hosted.https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=900

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Client side hooks are not reliable IMO (the client could always pass in --no-verify, or just remove the hook completely).  You'd want to use a server side hook that would reject any pushes that had commits with bad email addresses, and then print out recovery instructions for the end user on how to redo their commits with proper email addresses.

If you have existing commits in published history you don't have any non-destructive options for fixing those.

-A

This is a very rough sample that only correctly handles an existing branch update.  You will need to add a lot more cases to handle new branches, deletes, tags, etc., as well as instructions on how they can configure their email and how to recreate the commits with correct email information.  But it should get you started.

.git/hooks/update

```
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

for sha in $(git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev})
do
   git log ${sha}  --format="%ae %ce" -1 | grep [A-Z]
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      echo "SHA ${sha} contains an illegal email address containing uppercase characters"
      git log ${sha} --format="%ae %ce" -1
      exit 1
   fi
done
```

If you try to push a SHA you will get something like this

> remote: SHA 49511d51548720f774b4a2bed113c43d06c32a34 contains an
>   illegal email address containing uppercase characters remote:
>   AndrewC@whoops.com  remote: error: hook declined to update
>   refs/heads/master To /scratch/email_repo  ! [remote rejected] master
>   -> master (hook declined)

Comment: Thanks. As you say, I agree that client side hooks are not reliable. I was thinking to implement this on the remote server side, so that every push to it will be verified before getting added?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure is it off-topic but why you have to force users to use email in lowercase? The local-part (part before @) of email address can be case sensitive.

Jeyanthan@serverA.com and JEYANTHAN@serverA.com  can be a different email address and it's all depending on serverA.com.

See RFC

Verbs and argument values (e.g., "TO:" or "to:" in the RCPT command
and extension name keywords) are not case sensitive, with the sole
exception in this specification of a mailbox local-part (SMTP
Extensions may explicitly specify case-sensitive elements).  That is,
a command verb, an argument value other than a mailbox local-part,
and free form text MAY be encoded in upper case, lower case, or any
mixture of upper and lower case with no impact on its meaning.  ***The
local-part of a mailbox MUST BE treated as case sensitive.***

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.4

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Common_local-part_semantics

If you find any problem importing upper case email address, i think it is NOT to address this issue in git but should be on that importing program

Comment: The issue not with Git, but with the underlying integration. Git is hosted by Gerrit and Gerrit is unfortunately case sensitive. It leads to issues like this - https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=900.

Comment: Gerrit already said it is not a bug https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=900#c5 . The problem is the user register their email at Gerrit by one case, and configure their git email config by another. Is it easier to request all users to update their local git email config to align what they registered in Gerrit?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered addressing this in code delivery and peer review?

For example, you can adopt a practice where new deliveries are done on a `feature` branch and only once they are completed (and reviewed) they get merged into an `integration` branch. As a part of code review you can require that the person(s) performing the review check the commit history, by switching into the feature branch, for

1. Proper `user.email`
2. Proper `user.name`
3. Meaningful commit messages
4. Squashed commits for like changes

This approach does require discipline but the outcome would yield a 'clean' `integration` branch where you would not have to run `git filter-branch` all the time.

If you are using Github, and have forks and pull-requests in the picture, the same can be done but would have to be done before someone pushes the green 'merge this' button.

Answer (score 2):

To be brutally honest, you have a people problem, not a technology problem. The real issue is that people are unaware or don't care.

Anyone with write access to the repo needs to be made aware of this and assisted. If you are dealing with 3rd parties, deny pull requests if they don't follow the standards.

Comment: Thanks @morgajel. Users were instructed earlier. They face the consequence now when the underlying Gerrit fails to accept mixed cases - https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=900 . Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I falls under "Gerrit is case sensitive regarding email addresses. Nothing I can do about that, so you'll have to suffer with being consistent. It will fail if you are not."  There is only so much mental bandwidth in a day; pick and choose your battles.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function `mygit` (or whatever name you want) as a wrapper to the normal `git`.

This for example checks every single argument that is given. In case they contain any character different from a digit, a lower case or a @, it shows an error and exits. Otherwise, the `git` command is executed normally.

```
mygit () {
    for var in "$@"
    do
      echo "arg is: $var"
          if [[ "$var" =~ [^0-9a-z@] ]]; then
        echo "argument $var has characters not being 0-9, a-z or @"
        return
      fi
    done
    git $@
}
```

To use it permanently, store it in your `~/.bashrc` file. You can even make `git` itself behave like `mygit` does. You just need to set an alias: `alias git=mygit` or change the function to be called `git`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @fedorque. I just thought of implementing this on the server instead of the client, so that it verifies every time when there is a push coming to it.

Comment: I don't see how this would possibly be useful to fix this problem, and you would end up with a completely broken version of Git if you tried to use it.  The email address is not passed in via the command line to Git.

Comment: @Jeyanthan yes, this could be a better approach. Probably part of my code could help (the bash string comparison).

Comment: @AndrewC I am not very expert on git so I don't know where the email is supplied. In my experience I sometimes set it up with the `git config ...`. What is the generic case?

Comment: There isn't really one.  Git will read the config variable user.email if it exists and use that as the committer when you create a new commit, but you can override that via environmental variables and it differs if your workflow involves cherry-pick or am