# How to create a GitLab hook to reject code pushed by 'root' user?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I work with an undisciplined team and one of the developers likes to push code as the 'root' user. We need to add a gitlab hook that rejects those commits coming from the 'root' user.

I've read about [System Hooks](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/system_hooks.html) and [Web Hooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md), neither of which seems like the right direction.

Can one of you gitlab gurus help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to reject pushes performed by the root user, or pushes of commits by a particular user, e.g. `root <root@localhost>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540258/how-to-force-users-to-use-email-address-in-lowercase-in-git/25899800#25899800 - just change the grep part of my answer here to look for root - if you are looking to suppress commits authored or committed by root user

Comment: you need to set up a pre-receive hook for the git repository. Have a look at [that article](http://www.androider.me/2014/03/how-to-add-pre-receive-hook-in-gitlab.html) on setting it up for gitlab

Comment: @Chris, one of the developers likes to login as root on a remote machine and do development there. He then pushes the code as 'root'. We want to reject those pushes. It is a long story as to why.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, that's what we need. If you want to provide an answer below, I'll mark it accepted. zmo, in fairness to Andrew I'll give him a chance to formally answer the question first.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not overly worried about reputation points (and zmo attributed and modified, which is fine by me), go ahead and accept zmo's and upvote my original if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a server side `pre-receive` hook that will check the user. You can do it with a script such as [Andrew C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540258/how-to-force-users-to-use-email-address-in-lowercase-in-git/25899800#25899800)'s:

```
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

for sha in $(git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev})
do
   git log ${sha}  --format="%ae %ce" -1 | grep 'root@'
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]
   then
      echo "SHA ${sha} a root email address. Please use your user credentials!"
      git log ${sha} --format="%ae %ce" -1
      exit 1
   fi:
done
```

or you could make a ruby version of it, using their API to browse through commits

Comment: Just wanted to make sure everyone knows that that script *only* handles the case where you are updating an existing ref. A full solution would need to cover a bunch of additional cases -   For instance, if ${oldrev} didn't exist.

Comment: Right, which is why using the Ruby API offered by gitlab could be worth a try!